# Gawk cross referencing fields and inserting value

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I wish to expand on this cross referencing script, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Current script >

```
gawk -F"\t" '
    FNR==NR{a[$1][$2]=1;next}
    $2 in a{for(i in a[$2]) print $1 FS i}
' a.txt b.txt
```

Example of a.txt:

```
Email@gmail.com    hello example
Email@gmail.com    hello world
```

Example of b.txt:

```
Charles    Email@gmail.com
Erica    Email@gmail.com
```

Output >

```
Charles    hello example
Charles    hello world
Erica    hello example
Erica    hello world
```

Basically this script checks to see whether `$1` in `a.txt` is equal to `$2` in `b.txt` and if so then output `$2` from `a.txt` alongside `$1` in `b.txt` ( as seen above )

I wish to use a different format though and edit `b.txt` directly, example of desired outcome >

`a.txt` will remain the same as above.

Example of b.txt:

```
Charles    Email@gmail.com    0    msg    example
Erica    Email@gmail.com    0    msg    example
```

so now `b.txt` has 5 columns, we'll match `$2` from `b.txt` to `$1` from a.txt as before but insert `$2` from a.txt into `$4` b.txt replacing the current value with the new one if any.

Also I want to `ignore-case` on matches, but I guess I can just wrap `$1,$2,etc` with `tolower()`?

Desired output >

```
Charles    Email@gmail.com    0    hello example    example
Erica    Email@gmail.com    0    hello example    example
```

Comment: You made your question much harder to understand and test by using the same email address `Email@gmail.com` for both Charles and Erica. The domain `example.com` exists for us to use to be able to create fake email addresses, URLs, etc. without clashing with anyones real address so you should really be using something like `charles@example.com` and `erica@example.com` where applicable in your example instead of `Email@gmail.com`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modificating a bit your original script,

```
awk '
    BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
    #Parsing first file
    FNR==NR{a[tolower($1)]=$2;next}
    #Parsing second file
    {
        i=tolower($2)
        if(i in a){$4=a[i];print}
    }
' a.txt b.txt > c.txt &&
mv c.txt b.txt
```

`tolower` is used to match the 1st field of `a.txt` with the 2nd of `b.txt` case-insensitively.

The output is stored in a temporary file `c.txt`, which then overwrites the `b.txt` if `awk` exited successfully.

Comment: Quasimodo thank you :)!

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
    { split(tolower($0),lc) }
    NR==FNR {
        a[lc[1]] = $2
        next
    }
    lc[2] in a {
        $4 = a[lc[2]]
        print
    }
' a.txt b.txt
```